# Data factory list run pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to list azure pipelines run for a given data factory pipeline resource. The account I am using has Contributor role to the data factory resource.

But I get a permission error when I try to query running pipelines

`await client.PipelineRuns.QueryByFactoryAsync(dataFactoryResourceName, factoryRG ...`

So question I have is why Contributor role is not sufficient to be able to list pipelines. From role description, it sounds like Contributor role should have all required access. [ContributorRole permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdVXg.png) Is this a bug in implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my test, Contributor role is enough. You need to set your AAD application as Contributor.

[image]

My test code:

```
    var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + tenantID);
    ClientCredential cc = new ClientCredential(applicationId, authenticationKey);
    AuthenticationResult result = context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/", cc).Result;
    ServiceClientCredentials cred = new TokenCredentials(result.AccessToken);
    client = new DataFactoryManagementClient(cred)
    {
        SubscriptionId = subscriptionId
    };
    PipelineRunsQueryResponse response = await client.PipelineRuns.QueryByFactoryAsync(dataFactoryResourceName, factoryName,new RunFilterParameters());
    Console.WriteLine(response.Value.Count);
```